# How to use redux-persist for selcted item API call

Tags: android, react-native, redux, wix-react-native-navigation, redux-persist

I am making an app in react-native for android using redux and using Wix's react-native-navigation to navigate between screens. I am storing a list of all data fetched from API into the redux store. I am using redux-persist to display list present in the store if the user is offline. In the app after clicking on any item, it goes to a new page and calls new API with selected item id like `fetch(constants.BaseURL + /api/detail/${id}`. Now I want to display this data also in offline mode how can I do that?

My configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';

import masjids from "./reducers/productReducer";
import { root } from "./reducers/rootReducer";


const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
} 

const reducers = {
  root,
  masjids
}

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, reducers)

let composeEnhancers = compose;

if (__DEV__) {
  composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
};

export default configureStore;
```

I was wondering if anyone would like to share their solution. Thanks in advance.

productReducer.js

```
import * as types from "../actions/masjidList/ActionTypes";

  const initialState = {
    items: [],
  };

  export default function masjidListReducer(
    state = initialState,
    action
  ) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.FETCH_MASJIDS_SUCCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          items: action.payload.masjids
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

rootReducer.js

```
import * as types from '../actions/login/ActionTypes';
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';

const initialState = Immutable({
  root: undefined, // 'login' / 'after-login' / 'register'
});

//root reducer
export function root(state = initialState, action = {}) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case types.ROOT_CHANGED:
    return {...state,root:action.root}

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass all of your reducers to the store. The ones that are passed will be persisted. Make sure you store the response after fetching. I suggest you make separate reducer file and use combineReducers call to get a singleton object.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

//import all the reducers
import reducers from '../reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  {},
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I think you didn't get my question. redux-persist is working properly for the list but I want for detail.

Comment: Is it okay for you to share productReducer.js and rootReducer.js

Comment: You must put the fetched data in the store as well.

Comment: You might be using the persistCombineReducers function in the wrong way. Why don't you try combining all the reducers using combineReducers function and then pass the reducers to persistReducer function instead of persistCombineReducers.